# Work out the period of a sine graph $h(x)= 50-40\sin(\frac{4\pi x}{3})$

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

I need some help with how to work out the period of this sine graph equation.

$$h(x)= 50-40\sin\left(\frac{4\pi x}{3}\right)$$

I have a question that asks me to graph it, and I have worked out the amplitude to be $50$.

I understand that if it is $3x$ on its own, the period will be $2\pi/3$, and that if it is $x/3$ for example, the period will be $6\pi$.

What I am unsure of is how to work it out when multiple steps are involved as well as when $\pi$ is used.

Could someone please explain in simple steps how to solve this. Thankyou :)

Comment: `i have worked out the amplitude to be 50` That doesn't sound right, but you should mention what definition of `amplitude` you are working with, anyway. `I need some help with how to work out the period` Find the minimum $\,T\,$ such that $\,h(x)=h(x+T)\,$ holds for $\,\forall x\,$.

Comment: The number $50$ represents the vertical shift, not the period.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The trigonometric function
$$f(x) = A\sin(Bx - C) + D$$
has amplitude $|A|$, period $2\pi/|B|$, phase shift $C/B$, and vertical shift $D$.

We can express the function 
$$h(x) = 50 - 40\sin\left(\frac{4\pi x}{3}\right)$$
in the form 
$$h(x) = -40\sin\left(\frac{4\pi}{3}x - 0\right) + 50$$
so 
$A = -40$, $B = \dfrac{4\pi}{3}$, $C = 0$, and $D = 50$.  Using the stated formulas yields an amplitude of 
$$|A| = |-40| = 40$$
a period of 
$$\frac{2\pi}{|B|} = \frac{2\pi}{\frac{4\pi}{3}} = 2\pi \cdot \frac{3}{4\pi} = \frac{3}{2}$$
a phase shift of 
$$\frac{C}{B} = \frac{0}{\frac{4\pi}{3}} = 0$$
and a vertical shift of 
$$D = 50$$

Answer (score 0):

After one period $T$ the argument of the sine function has gone from 0 to $2\pi$

Solve $\frac{4\pi T}{3}=2\pi$

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, we know that the period when we have $\sin(x)$ is $2\pi$. When multiplying by a constant inside the $\sin$, you could see this as "accelerating" the function. And so, if we multiply by a constant $c>1$, our function $\sin(cx)$ will go faster, and thus the period will be smaller (and similarly, if $0<c<1$ we are slowing down the function, and the period of $\sin(cx)$ will be larger).

In this case, we are acceleration the function by a constant $c=\frac{4\pi}{3}$. The period will then be $\frac{2\pi}{c}=\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: How to you go from c=4π/ 3 to 2π /c ?